# Intuitive understanding

Tags: java

On this page: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

> A class contains constructors that are invoked to create objects from
>   the class blueprint. Constructor declarations look like method
>   declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no
>   return type. For example, `Bicycle` has one constructor:
>
> ```
> public Bicycle(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) {
>     gear = startGear;
>     cadence = startCadence;
>     speed = startSpeed;
> }
> ```
>
> To create a new Bicycle object called `myBike`, a constructor is
>   called by the new operator:
>
> ```
> Bicycle myBike = new Bicycle(30, 0, 8);
> ```
>
> `new Bicycle(30, 0, 8)` creates space in memory for the object and
>   initializes its fields."

So I've done JS before and over there declaring a new object would be something like `var newObject = new Bicycle(params);`

However, what I've noticed here is that when you are creating a new object, you say `Bicycle myBike = new Bicycle(params);`

Why is the word Bicycle used twice? How does that work?

Comment: Something that the answers so far haven't explicitly called out is that the reason that specifying `Bicycle` twice isn't redundant is that while in *this* case the type of both the variable and the object is the same, that is not always the case.

Comment: C# added the "var" keyword to reduce the Bicycle Bicycle factor (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx). I still haven't decided if that actually makes things better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java prefers explicit declarations for what the objects intended use is. For instance, when you create an integer you preface if with **int**. In a similar fashion, the Java compiler wants to know what the object you are creating is going to be. Thus we have to tell it that its going to be a specific class. All Java variables (to the best of my knowledge) follow this same pattern. It was the way the language was designed. Other languages generally use similar constructs, or have room for a **var** variable.

The first instance of the word Bicycle declares the type of variable you are using. The second is used to create a new object of type bicycle. The second use of the word is the same as calling a method.

Albeit I do agree, it seems slightly redundant in a case like this. I assume its because of the object oriented nature of Java that we need to restrict it. (e.g. you could have funny situations where object inherit from other objects).

Answer (score 3):

```
Bicycle myBike = new Bicycle(30, 0, 8);
```

Two primary things happening here in the one statement:

1.

```
Bicycle myBike;
```

This is the variable declaration, where the variable name and type is specified.

2.

```
myBike = new Bicycle(30, 0, 8);
```

This is the variable initialization, where the value is assigned.

Comment: Is it correct to say that the value is assigned to the variable?

Since this is just an object reference, and the variable doesn't actually hold the actual object itself.

Answer (score 2):

In JS , every variable is referred as `var` type. Its kind of generic, but in `java` every object has one of the type like `Bicycle` here. So it basically depends on the syntax that a language follows.

`Bicycle myBike = new Bicycle(30, 0, 8);` in this `Bicycle myBike` declares a refrence variable `myBike` of `Bicycle` type & `new Bicycle(30, 0, 8);` creates a new Instance of `Bicycle` with initial values as `30,0,8`  and `=` assigns this instance to the  `myBike` variable.

Comment: Both JS and Java are object-oriented. JS has inheritance, it's just prototypal vs class-based.

Comment: @NathanHughes edited that, earlier was not sure about this. Thanks for clearing

Answer (score 1):

First part (before the `=` defines an *object reference*, second part (after the `=`) *constructs* a new object. The `=` does the *assignment*.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way that's explained in "Head First Java" that you might find a bit more intuitive (It makes a lot more sense to me)

Take the statement 
`Bicycle myBike = new Bicycle(params);`

And break it up into:

```
Bicycle myBike;
myBike = new Bicycle(params);
```

Now imagine `myBike` as a remote, and `Bicycle(params)` as the object the remote is controlling.

So those two lines are saying:

The first line:

`Make a remote called myBike that will control an object of type Bicycle`.

Then the second line is saying: `The specific Bicycle that myBike will control is a new Bicycle with these parameters.`

I think that is a much more intuitive explanation.

The way you present it, it's just taking those statements into one line (to save some space).

So to left of the equal sign you are telling the compiler to make a variable called `myBike` that can ONLY be linked to an object that is of type `Bicycle` and the equal sign is telling you exactly which `Bicycle` you are linking this reference to: In this case, a `new Bicycle(params)`.